# MySQL Update Query using two parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code at the end of a rather lengthy update query (I cut out the rest of the code for readability):

```
WHERE username = '$username' AND charname = '$charname'"
```

This function checks that a character belongs to the user and that the function is updating the proper character.

When I try to use the update function on the page, I get the following text:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Myusername' AND charname = 'Mycharacter'' at line 1

Some quick notes:

Myusername is the username for the account that created this character.  The code retrieves that through a session variable after the user logs in.

Mycharacter is the name of the character that the user is trying to update.  It is retrieved from a text box on the same page when the user clicks the button that activates this function.

I've combed through the MySQL update query that precedes the WHERE pretty thoroughly, and the syntax all seems fine, so I am stumped as to why this doesn't work!

Edit:  Just for reference, here is the whole query. Fair warning, it is very long.. and if you are a Fallout fan, you might be able to figure out what I am trying to do ;)

```
$update = "UPDATE Publicchars 
            SET chargender = '$chargender',
                ruleset = '$ruleset', level = '$level',
                hp = '$hp', ap = '$ap',
                carryweight = '$carryweight', defenses = '$defenses',
                strength = '$strength', perception = '$perception',
                endurance = '$endurance', charisma = '$charisma',
                intelligence = '$intelligence', agility = '$agility',
                luck = '$luck', skills = '$skills',
                perks = '$perks', traits = '$traits',
                implants = '$implants', abilities = '$abilities',
                weapons = '$weapons', armor = '$armor',
                ammo = '$ammo', drugs = '$drugs',
                food = '$food', alcohol = '$alcohol',
                meds = '$meds', items = '$items',
                karma = '$karma', reputation = '$reputation',
                accomplishments = '$accomplishments',
                backstory = '$backstory', notes = '$notes'  
            WHERE username = '".$username."' 
              AND charname = '".$charname."'";
```

Comment: can you show us the entire query? also are you using two tables?

Comment: Where is the **actual code** you're using for this query? How is it run?

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Show us the full query. It could be as simple as missing a space before the WHERE but not noticing it if the statement is wrapped.

Comment: Your example has a trailing speech mark. Could that be it?

Comment: I edited this to add the full query in.  The quotation mark at the end was simply the end of whole query.

Comment: Also to note - I have tried this both with concatenators and without, as well as using the session variable directly rather than assigning it to the $username value.

Comment: Can you also share the **fully rendered** query (not the PHP version)? I'm guessing that `$notes` has some illegal characters in it (such as a `"` or `'`) which is causing it to break....

Comment: Debugging 101: If error makes no sense, `ECHO $update;` and look at the string with all the `$vars` expanded. You will almost always see the Woops

Comment: There's probably a quote in one of the variables. This is why you should use a prepared query instead of variable substitution.

Comment: You're missing a `'` after $reputation

Comment: @RyanGee Eagle eye :-0 So lets close this as a TYPO

Comment: I did just swap that one out and it is still returning the same error, but a typo somewhere else could be the problem too

Comment: Are you getting the same exact error?

Comment: Yep, same exact text as before: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Myusername' AND charname = 'Mycharacter'' at line 1

Comment: I'm noticing `Mycharacter` ending with a dbl quote versus a single.

Comment: There we go - it was a combination of fixing the typo and getting rid of all the concatenators that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an `'` after $reputation.

Then try:

`WHERE username = '$username' AND charname = '$charname'";`

This seems to keep my syntax highlighting happy at least...

Comment: This works for me `WHERE username = '".$username."' && charname = '".$charname."'`

Comment: There we go - it was a combination of fixing the typo and getting rid of all the concatenators that fixed the issue edit:  That, and some of those fields were not set to VARCHAR, which was probably also causing issues.